# How to make x axis depend on two columns in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

**Problem**:

I have a chart - its **X** axis must contain 2 parameters (2 columns), a number and a date, which each date contains a few numbers.

Here are my chart and what I want:

[image: Chart]

My attempt:

```
Chart1.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "tgl"
Chart1.Series("Series2").XValueMember = "tgl"
Chart1.Series("Series3").XValueMember = "tgl"
Chart1.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "TC30"
Chart1.Series("Series2").YValueMembers = "ABA353TC30usl"
Chart1.Series("Series3").YValueMembers = "ABA353TC30lsl"
```

Is it possible to make it like this?

Comment: Your desired chart is NOTHING like the undesired chart.  Please post a [mcve] Not just some snippet of code.  Then we may be able to help you